# Angular 4 access service variable from serviceworker and app.module

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, angular-service-worker

In an Angular 4 project, I have some information stored in a json file. That information contains custom configuration, and some of it is needed in the app.module.ts and in the Service Worker.

That json file content is also put into a variable of an injectable service, so I guess both accessing the json file or acccessing that service variable would do. This is the service in which I put the json file in a variable:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

public appConfig: AppConfigRoot;

constructor( private http: Http )
{ this.loadAppConfigFile(); }

loadAppConfigFile() {
 this.http.get("/assets/config/app.config.json").map((res) => 
 res.json()).subscribe(data => {
  this.appConfig = data;
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: What's your question exactly? I CTRL + F for the ? but was not able to find it.

Comment: Sorry, the question is, is it possible to retrieve some custom configuration from a json file and put it in the app.module.ts and in the serviceworker?